# Проблема со стилями в выпадающем меню

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер. Такая проблема: в выпадающем меню между ссылками большое пространство. До того как я вставила ссылки, все было нормально

```css
.dropOut ul {
   float: left;
   padding: 10px 0;
}
.dropOut ul li {
   text-align: left;
   float: left;
   width: auto;
   padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
   margin: 0px 10px;
   color: #777;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -mox-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;
   -o-transition: background .1s ease-out;
   transition: background .1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownContain">
   <div class="dropOut">
      <ul>
         <a href="pvh.html#sib"><li>Окна Rehau Sib-Design</li></a>
         <a href="pvh.html#geneo"><li>Окна Rehau Geneo</li></a>
         <a href="pvh.html#euro"><li>Окна Rehau Euro-Design</li></a>
         <a href="pvh.html#interlio"><li>Окна Rehau Intelio</li></a>
         <a href="pvh.html#brilliant"><li>Окна Rehau Brillant-design</li></a>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

вот оно "большое расстояние" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код должен быть не в виде картинок, а в виде текста. пожалуйста перенесите код из картинок в вопрос.

Comment: У вас ошибка: `li` не может быть обёрнут в `a`. Укажите те стили, который вы указали для `li` для блока `a`

Comment: Простите, а что вы имеете введу под: большое расстояние?

Comment: @Yuri добавила скриншот

Comment: @супераня мне почему-то кажется, что там наследуется от родителя какой-то стиль. Было бы куда проще решить вопрос имея ссылку на сайт или код страницы целиком.  Для стандартного `margin`  и `padding` у маркированного списка отступ очень большой. Так же, разместите ссылки внутри пунктов `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте для `ul` стиль `margin: 0`. По стандарту, у `ul` установлен отступ:

```
.dropOut ul {
   float: left;
   padding: 10px 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `ul` из разметки и замените его на тег `nav`. Проблема в том, что `ul` имеет дефолтный `padding`. Да и с точки зрения валидности так будет правильней, ведь у вас `ul` идет без `li`. Или же сбросьте стили для списков:

```
// Remove default margins
ul, ol, menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-padding: 0;
    -webkit-padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Если убрать `ul`, то не совсем правильная структура меню выйдет

Comment: Наоборот ul без li - невалиден. Да и вообще лучше div заменить на nav.

Comment: Я обычно просто `margin: 0` ставлю и никаких проблем

Comment: А я просто использую div для меню.